# How to download Image collection from google earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to save each image of this collection into my drive.

```
var filtered_Image=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 138))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 45))
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',20)
.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-06-31')
.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4']);
```

Comment: You may accept the answer if it fulfilled your requirement, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://code.earthengine.google.com/15f748dffa93c031eac646e449981d9d)

choose your geometry/point of interest from imports.
[image: geometry/point of interest]

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');


var filtered_Image=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')
                     .filterBounds(POI)
                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 138))
                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 45))
                     .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',20)
                     .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                     .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4']);

Map.setCenter(88, 21, 7);

var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.5,
  gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};

Map.addLayer (filtered_Image.first(),  vizParams, 'false color composite')


batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(filtered_Image, 'Landsat8', {
  name: 'filtered_Image_{system:index}',
  type: 'float',
  scale: 30,
  region: POI
});
```

Comment: thank you sir it works for me. thank you so much.

Comment: @SomaMitra https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: can clip out my POI area before download and then download clipped out images to my drive ? suppose this is my point of interest. 1: [89.12948520154367,21.447198448090315]
2: [89.12948520154367,22.018698713000738]
3: [88.22860629529367,22.018698713000738]
4: [88.22860629529367,21.447198448090315]

Comment: @SomaMitra I have updated the code to clip your area of interest

Comment: @Avilash sir thank you.

Comment: @avilash sir can you suggest any good google earth engine tutorial from beginners to advance level?